# how to setup the sphinx with netbeans

Tags: netbeans, sphinx4

i have successfully configured sphinx4 with eclipse.

for that these steps i have used.

1. copy my java and config files to SRC folder
2. all the necessary jar files (in the lib). the lib folder added to the root of the project
3. build those jar files (jsapi files too)
4. change the configuration file and give the proper path
5. test the java file

but in Netbeans i really dont understand how to do the proper steps. can someone help me. the jar files should be added to "Libraries" rite.
then after adding them how to build them. 
in the netbeans it dont show a SRC folder. so all the java files and configuration files should go to Source Packages folder rite.

can someone help me with this. please

Answer (score 3):

If you have sphinx4-1.0beta6 then you can just open the folder up as a netbeans project. Open netbeans, click open project, then navigate to the sphinx folder and open it. It is already a netbeans project file type as of this version. I assume this will work in later versions also. I have no clue why sphinx doesn't say this on their website.

Comment: As for today, sphinx4 does not recommend to use version 1.0beta6

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx4 is a Java library available in [OSS](https://oss.sonatype.org) repository, so you can use it as any library.

If your project uses maven/gradle, add repository in your project configuration, then add dependency on two packages - sphinx4 core and sphinx4-data. The former is the main library, the latter is required if you want to recognize US English. Then just start writing the code.

If you want to rely on jar files, just download sphinx4-core and sphinx4-data files from the repository and add them as dependency to the project, then start writing code.

If you want to modify or develop sphinx4 itself, install [Gradle](http://gradle.org) support in your IDE, then import latest sphinx4 sources as a Gradle project.

For more details and links see the tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

Answer (score 0):

[image]

click on Add JAR/Folder
[image]
select jar file you want to add

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~edu.cmu.sphinx  you can use this link to download jar files sphinx4-data and sphinx4-code